# My post request doesn't save all my data in my schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My problem I'm facing right now is that my post request that suppose to save my doc in my mongodb doesn't save all my docs. It doesn't save the fields with multiple values. Is there a way to save those?

This is my post request.

```
router.post('/register',function(req,res,next){
    let newDoc = new Doc({
        patientInfo:{
            Name:{      
                fname:req.body.fname,
                lname:req.body.lname,
                mname:req.body.mname
            },
        age:req.body.age,
        address:{
            barangay:req.body.barangay,
            cc:req.body.cc,
            city:req.body.city
        },
        birthday:req.body.birtday,
        complaint:req.body.complaint,
        vitalsign:{
            time:req.body.time,
            pulse:req.body.pulse,
            bp:req.body.bp,
            resp:req.body.resp,
            temp:req.body.temp,
            Sao:req.body.Sao,
            levelofconsciousness:req.body.levelofconsciousness,
            airway:req.body.airway,
            o2supply:req.body.o2supply,
            breathing:req.body.breathing,
            capref:req.body.capref,
            bloodsugar:req.body.bloodsugar,
            anatomicalchart:req.body.anatomicalchart
        }
        },
    managementnotes:req.body.managementnotes,
    date:{
        month:req.body.month,
        dateN:req.body.dateN,
        year:req.body.year
    },
    nameofcaller:req.body.nameofcaller,
    teamresponder:req.body.teamresponder,
    emergencyroutetimerecord:{
        callrecieved:req.body.callrecieved,
        respondtime:req.body.respondtime,
        arrivaltoscene:req.body.arrivaltoscene,
        leftscene:req.body.leftscene,
        hospitalarrival:req.body.hospitalarrival,
        acdrrmoarrival:req.body.acdrrmoarrival
    },
    natureaccident:[
        req.body.natureaccident
    ],
    vehicleinvolved:req.body.vehicleinvolved,
    incidentlocation:req.body.incidentlocation
    });
    Doc.addDocument(newDoc,function(err,callback){
        console.log(newDoc);
        if(err) res.json({success:false,msg:"ERROR SAVING DOC OCCURED"});
        else res.json({success:true,msg:"Saved"});
    });
});
```

And it returns me this json

```
{ __v: 0,
  managementnotes: 'req.body.managementnotes',
  nameofcaller: 'req.body.nameofcaller',
  teamresponder: 'req.body.teamresponder',
  vehicleinvolved: 'req.body.vehicleinvolved',
  incidentlocation: 'req.body.incidentlocation',
  _id: 597b6f1806cb8e2710e5d8f9,
  natureaccident: [ 'req.body.natureaccident' ] }
```

And this is how I save the doc

```
module.exports.addDocument = function(newDoc,callback){
    newDoc.save(callback);
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is my mongoose schema

```
var DocSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    patientInfo:{
        Name:{
            fname:{
                type:String
            },
            mname:{
                type:String
            },
            fname:{
                type:String
            }
        },
        age:{
            type:Number
        },
        address:{
            barangay:{
                type:String
            },
            cc:{//country
                type:String
            }
        },
        birthday:{
            type:String
        },
        complaint:{
            type:String
        },
        vitalsign:{
            time:{
                type:String
            },
            pulse:{
                type:String
            },
            bp:{
                type:String
            },
            resp:{
                type:String
            },
            temp:{
                type:String
            },
            Sao:{
                type:String
            },
            levelofconsciousness:{
                type:String
            },
            airway:{
                type:String
            },
            o2supply:{
                type:String
            },
            breathing:{
                type:String
            },
            capref:{
                type:String
            },
            bloodsugar:{
                type:String
            },
            anatoymicalchart:{
                type:String
            }
        }

    },
    managementnotes:{
        type:String
    },
    date:{
        month:{
            type:String
        },
        dateN:{
            type:String
        },
        year:{
            type:String
        }
    },
    nameofcaller:{
        type:String
    },
    teamresponder:{
        type:String
    },
    emergencyroutetimerecord:{
        callrecieved:{
            type:String
        },
        respondtime:{
            type:String
        },
        arrivaltoscene:{
            type:String
        },
        leftscene:{
            type:String
        },
        hospitalarrival:{
            type:String
        },
        acdrrmoarrival:{
            type:String
        }
    },
    natureaccident:[{
        type:String
    }],
    vehicleinvolved:{
        type:String
    },
    incidentlocation:{
        type:String
    }

});
```

this is what my request look like

```
{
"patientInfo":{
            "Name":{      
                "fname":"tslph",
                "lname":"sdfsdf",
                "mname":"sdfsdfsd"
            },
        "age":12,
        "address":{
            "barangay":"req.body.barangay",
            "cc":"req.body.cc",
            "city":"req.body.city"
        },
        "birthday":"req.body.birtday",
        "complaint":"req.body.complaint",
        "vitalsign":{
            "time":"req.body.time",
            "pulse":"req.body.pulse",
            "bp":"req.body.bp",
            "resp":"req.body.resp",
            "temp":"req.body.temp",
            "Sao":"req.body.Sao",
            "levelofconsciousness":"req.body.levelofconsciousness",
            "airway":"req.body.airway",
            "o2supply":"req.body.o2supply",
            "breathing":"req.body.breathing",
            "capref":"req.body.capref",
            "bloodsugar":"req.body.bloodsugar",
            "anatomicalchart":"req.body.anatomicalchart"
        }
        },
    "managementnotes":"req.body.managementnotes",
    "date":{
        "month":"req.body.month",
        "dateN":"req.body.dateN",
        "year":"req.body.year"
    },
    "nameofcaller":"req.body.nameofcaller",
    "teamresponder":"req.body.teamresponder",
    "emergencyroutetimerecord":{
        "callrecieved":"req.body.callrecieved",
        "respondtime":"req.body.respondtime",
        "arrivaltoscene":"req.body.arrivaltoscene",
        "leftscene":"req.body.leftscene",
        "hospitalarrival":"req.body.hospitalarrival",
        "acdrrmoarrival":"req.body.acdrrmoarrival"
    },
    "natureaccident":[
        "req.body.natureaccident"
    ],
    "vehicleinvolved":"req.body.vehicleinvolved",
    "incidentlocation":"req.body.incidentlocation"
}
```

Comment: Most likely a schema definition mistake, could you post your mongoose schema?

Comment: @88jayto I've added the mongoose schema

Comment: @RalphMungucal I don't see anything immediately wrong with your schema, what does the request you sending to your server look like? I don't think mongoose will persist null/undefined values fyi

Comment: I've added the post request. @88jayto

Comment: @88jayto is there any other way to do this if nothing is wrong? I really need to finish this, I hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you are reading the params from the request incorrectly. You need to specify the full path to the values inside you objects like so:

```
 let newDoc = new Doc({
        patientInfo:{
            Name:{      
                fname:req.body.patientInfo.Name.fname,
                lname:req.body.patientInfo.Name.lname,
                mname:req.body.patientInfo.Name.mname
            },
        age:req.body.age,
        address:{
            barangay:req.body.patientInfo.address.barangay,
            cc:req.body.patientInfo.address.cc,
            city:req.body.patientInfo.address.city
        },
        birthday:req.body.patientInfo.birtday,
        complaint:req.body.patientInfo.complaint,
        vitalsign:{
            time:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.time,
            pulse:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.pulse,
            bp:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.bp,
            resp:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.resp,
            temp:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.temp,
            Sao:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.Sao,
            levelofconsciousness:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.levelofconsciousness,
            airway:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.airway,
            o2supply:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.o2supply,
            breathing:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.breathing,
            capref:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.capref,
            bloodsugar:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.bloodsugar,
            anatomicalchart:req.body.patientInfo.vitalsign.anatomicalchart
        }
        },
    managementnotes:req.body.managementnotes,
    date:{
        month:req.body.date.month,
        dateN:req.body.date.dateN,
        year:req.body.date.year
    },
    nameofcaller:req.body.nameofcaller,
    teamresponder:req.body.teamresponder,
    emergencyroutetimerecord:{
        callrecieved:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecordcallrecieved,
        respondtime:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecord.respondtime,
        arrivaltoscene:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecord.arrivaltoscene,
        leftscene:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecord.leftscene,
        hospitalarrival:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecord.hospitalarrival,
        acdrrmoarrival:req.body.emergencyroutetimerecord.acdrrmoarrival
    },
    natureaccident:[
        req.body.natureaccident
    ],
    vehicleinvolved:req.body.vehicleinvolved,
    incidentlocation:req.body.incidentlocation
    });
    Doc.addDocument(newDoc,function(err,callback){
        console.log(newDoc);
        if(err) res.json({success:false,msg:"ERROR SAVING DOC OCCURED"});
        else res.json({success:true,msg:"Saved"});
    });
```

Comment: Cannot read property &#39;fname&#39; of undefined it shows this error @88jayto

Comment: I missed one object level in your path, I updated the answer. @RalphMungcal

Comment: I've tried doing that but is only changes the error into Cannot read property &#39;Name&#39; of undefined @88jayto

Comment: it's a big object there are likely typos, at the top of your app do `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` to see what the object your getting actually looks like and fix the object and or the payload you are sending accordingly. @RalphMungcal

Comment: Ok thank you! I saw some typos on my request ahahaha @88jayto